# Bash with multiple spaces in single argument

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to figure out how to create a bash with multiple arguments, and one argument has multiple flags. I need to do this to open xterm, navigate to bash script, and execute it with arguments.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$Running_In_New_Xterm" != t ] ; then
Running_In_New_Xterm=exec xterm -hold -e "cd $3 && $1 $2"
Running_In_New_Xterm=t
fi
```

$2 is a command to run flags on $1 `-a blah -o blahblah`

I'm trying to determine the proper way to execute #2. I read I have to add ' ' when having an argument with multiple spaces, but I am trying that on the input side, and it isn't working. I get " unexpected EOF while looking for matching `' ' " which suggests my problem has something to do with the fact that $2 isn't being executed correctly. I'm at the point I think it has something to do with the bash itsel.

Comment: Apart from the issue of quoting and the shell's interpretation of the strings that you pass into that argument for `xterm`, you also assign `Running_In_New_Xterm` in the (environment of `xterm`) the value of `exec`. Is that a typo?

Comment: I am executing xterm if the conditions aren't meant ( != t). I've tried it, and it works. It's just for some reason I'm having difficulty passing the $2 flags through another script, even when I put ' ' outside them i.e. '-a blah -o blah blah'

Comment: Well, yes, I can see that. I was just curious about `Running_In_New_Xterm=exec`.

Comment: There is no typos that I can see

Comment: `-e "cd $3 && $1 $2"` does not work? What is the exact resulting command line you want executed (as you would type it into a shell)?

Answer (score 0):

`cd $3 && $1 $2` is not a program which can be called. You need

```
Running_In_New_Xterm=exec xterm -hold -e bash -c "cd $3 && $1 $2"
```

or (with quoting, if the arguments require that; `-a blah -o blahblah` should probably not be quoted)

```
Running_In_New_Xterm=exec xterm -hold -e bash -c "exec cd '$3' && exec '$1' '$2'"
```

Comment: No need of bash -c . Take a look at man xterm : One parameter (after all options) may be given.  That overrides xterm's
       built-in choice of shell program: but The -e option cannot be used with this parameter since it uses all
       parameters following the option.

Comment: @ctac_ But one parameter is not enough in this case.

Comment: what I want to say is 'cd $3 && $1 $2 is not a program which can be called' is false and the OP problem is not the shell. xterm always start a shell. If $1 is executable, the command line is ok.The issue is from quoting.I try this way and it's ok. "./scriptbash.sh 'ls' '-l *.txt' '../1'". I get in the xterm window the expected result : all files ended with .txt in the directory ../1